# RoR: Test object is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm new to Rails testing, I have this question:
Let's suppose this simple scenario where I have in my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
    if params[:user][:birth_date]
      Birthday.create(:title => "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}'s Birthday!", :date => params[:user][:birth_date].to_date, :user_id => @user.id)
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if params[:user][:birth_date]
      @birthday = Birthday.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
      @birthday.update_attributes(:date => params[:user][:birth_date].to_date) if @birthday
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test that every time a user is created the birthday event is created and that it's attributes are properly set. In my particular (real) case I have that a new object is created (or updated) when another object is created (or updated), and a lot of attributes are calculated and automatically set. I need to test that they are set correctly. How can I test it?

Comment: update will fail if the user doesn't already have a birthday

Comment: yes, anyway, it doesn't matter, this is a example i wrote very quickly to exemplify the situation as I'm not able to show the real code. The point here is testing, anyway thanks I will fix it now!

Comment: This logic should live in model

Comment: sound interesting, why do you think it should live in model? do you mean user model?

Comment: Yes, user model should be link to birthday through callback

Answer (score 0):

#### Test the Correct Objects

You want to test the object that is populating your User data, or possibly the callbacks in your User model. This is not generally a controller concern, especially if you follow the "fat model, skinny controller" paradigm.

In your specific case, your controller is calling Birthday#update_attributes, but the real changes are happening elsewhere, so that's where I'd test them. The only really useful tests for this particular controller would be ensuring that nothing is raised when you create or update your model data, but that's more of an integration test than a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Test::Unit or RSpec you can access the global variables through the "assigns"  method. As an example, you could use something like this:

```
post :update, :id => 1, :user => {:birthdate => '1/1/2000'}
assert_equal Date.new(2000, 1, 1), assigns(:user).birthday.date
```

You can also test that the database was updated correctly:

```
user = User.find(1)
assert_equal Date.new(2000, 1, 1), user.birthday.date
```